# Gitlab jobs failling (sudo: command not found OR Failed to fetch)

Tags: docker, gitlab, debian, gitlab-ci, sudo

I am using Gitlab Jobs to deploy a tool. The code below returns `sudo: command not found`. If I remove the `sudo` I get the following:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.138.132), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stable-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.130.132), connection timed out Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.66.132), connection timed out Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.2.132), connection timed out Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.194.132), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:80:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package latex209-bin
E: Unable to locate package texlive-latex-base
E: Unable to locate package texlive-latex-extra
E: Unable to locate package ant
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - deploy
variables:
  RA_NAME: "My_project"
default:
  before_script:
    - sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get install -y latex209-bin texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra ant && sudo apt-get install zip unzip
    
deploy_Default:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sh -x deploy.sh "$RA_NAME" "$(cat RA_VERSION)"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "${RA_NAME}_$(cat RA_VERSION).zip"
  only:
    - master
    - dev
    - tags
```

This has been happening for 1 week (most likely from the Gitlab 15.0 release).
Every Job before this started to happen `Passed` without any problems. Now, without changing anything they all fail (even trying to rerun old ones that `Passed`).
I tried adding

```
build_image:
  script:
    - docker build --network host
```

and a couple of similar configurations but none of them worked.

Now my question: why `sudo` doesn't work anymore without changing anything on my `.gitlab-ci.yml` and what can I do to solve it.
I should mention that these Jobs are triggered by commits to the branches mentioned in `only`. I can run them by running `pipeline` or rerun the ones that were already run. I am not aware of any other modality to run them. All the work with Gitlab and this Docker are done by Gitlab UI

Comment: Did you try to update your gitlab runner?

Comment: Hi, @alexandru-dudu! Can you give some information about the system Gitlab is installed on? Is it self hosted? Seems to me like it was caused by changes on the Debian system.

Comment: Hi. I don't have access to anything except for my code above and the UI interface. I thought it's because of the Debian update, but I am not sure how I can fix it, since I don't have any power on the gitlab instance. I was thinking maybe there is an alternative for the code that I have....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Before the update, without specifying any image in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, by default it used my company Docker Image [image].
 After the update I noticed it used another one [image]
I added to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` the following:

```
image: myCompanyImage
```

and now works fine as before.
If you encounter such a problem, check the image it's using and the image used in a previous successfully run pipeline.

Comment: You have room for improvement though. Why do you need to download all that stuff on the fly during your CI step? I would suggest creating a base image that has all the dependencies already in place thus avoiding both the unnecessary network bandwidth as well as potential issues like the one you encountered.

Comment: I'm the only developer in the team and I don't have experience in using these. I'm learning and improvement is one of my main goals. Thanks for advises

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the instance/server has networking issues. If the runner isn't self-hosted then Gitlab should fix the problem fairly soon. If the runner is self-hosted then you've got networking issues. Here's what I can propose:

Note: Try this without `sudo`

1. Select the debian mirror close to you from the [debian mirror sites list](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list)
2. Edit the sources list via `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` if `nano` is not available then use `vi`
3. Change to a different mirror

For example

```
http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/InRelease // <-- remove this
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/InRelease // <-- add this
```

4. Save.